# IE9 @font-face blues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face

So IE9 spits out an error on using a google fonts include like the following:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

IE9 spits out an error, even though the fonts still load fine:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
```

I'd gladly ignore this error if I weren't writing content that is iframed on other people's webpages. :(

Hosting the EOT files locally resolves the issue for IE:

```
< !--[if IE 9]>
< link rel="stylesheet" href="/survey/css/lato-ie.css" type="text/css" />
< ![endif]-->
```

And in that file..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/Lato-Reg-webfont.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url("/Lato-Bla-webfont.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
}
```

Include it in IE9, error's gone, works great.

Now my problem is, I need to include the google font stylesheet for everyone but IE9. For example, I can't do:

```
< !--[if !IE 9]>
< link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
< ![endif]-->
```

Or firefox won't even see the damn include.

Are IE's devs conspiring to waste all of our time?

Comment: Is there a strong disadvantage for you to host the fonts for all browsers?

Comment: Nothing other than effort and scalability (I'm going to need to do this for fonts for which I have no guarantee I'll be able to obtain a .woff, .ttf and .svg, let alone .eot)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track, you just need to use a [downlevel-revealed conditional comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment): it will hide it from IE but will be picked up by other browsers.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Maybe you didn't understand his problem but my solution resolves it.

Comment: I upvoted it back to zero for you, this is 100% the answer to the question, compact and simple too. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

One question, are you trying to view your files locally?

The google fonts doesnt render locally, even thou they are linked to absolute outside links. (In case of IEs)

```
localhost/project/index.html = good
C:\Project\index.html = bad
```

Comment: Good question, I'm viewing 'em through my local server though (not a C: path).